# How is fetch call working from command line when I specified an origin in my node js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I have the following settings in my node js (I'm using Express) app:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:5001',credentials: true }))
```

I am having cors issues with my React frontend (different story!). However, I wrote a simple JS script using fetch:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'       
 var response = await fetch('http://remote_server.com', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })

var data = await response.json()
console.log(data)
```

The above code works when run from my VSCode Terminal (localhost is NOT running)!? Why is it working even though I specified the origin in my backend code?

Comment: Does [this](//stackoverflow.com/a/35553666) answer your question?

Comment: CORS is a browser technology and likely the terminal you are using is executing the fetch call in node. Node, being server side, doesn't care about the CORS response headers and just ignores them. CORS protects against attacks that only make sense on a browser client. To clarify when you have CORS on, its not your backend that drops the requests, its the client (browser) that prevents the response from being read for security reasons. This client (node) doesn't even implement it.

Comment: @adsy: makes sense! Having said that, how can I send cookies to the backend while using fetch from the command line?

Comment: With browsers, it parses the `set-cookie` header in a server response and then automatically sends that in the `cookie` header for future requests. This wont be there on the node client, so you'd have to manually pass the `Cookie` header in the `fetch` options.

Comment: BTW you could use https://github.com/valeriangalliat/fetch-cookie to emulate what a browser does in node